# HERE Routing API: No Truck Route Found

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm trying to calculate a trucking route between 2 GPS locations using HERE Maps API but when trying to retrieve the data I get a 'NoRouteFound' `error: NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED_CHECK_OPTIONS`. I noticed it returns data when changing the mode from 'truck' but unfortunately I need the trucking route.

Here is the request that I'm trying to send across:

https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=XXXXXXXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXXXXXXX&waypoint0=geo!32.97756,-97.24956&waypoint1=geo!32.64868,-97.304&waypoint2=geo!30.6420454,-86.9787374&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-1&metricSystem=imperial&routeAttributes=sh

Any suggestions or workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing the same at our end, the intermediate waypoint doesn't seem correct. Only using origin and destination do give correct route with truck profile. can you modify/ change the intermediate waypoint to get the desired result.

https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?routeattributes=sh,gr&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;tollroad:0&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&language=en-us&trucktype=tractorTruck&jsonattributes=41&metricsystem=metric&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!32.97756,-97.24956&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!30.6420454,-86.9787374&app_code=XXX&app_id=XXXXX

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I need the truck profile from origin to the intermediate waypoint. Still receiving the same error when using those coordinates with your request format. But I think the coordinates should be correct as I get data when changing the TransportMode?